# Detecting if a URL contains a certain string but NOT as a parameter using PHP

Tags: php, development-environment, url-parameters, strpos

I'm trying to force different modes of debugging based on different development urls using PHP. I currently have this set up:

```
$protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']), 'https') === FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$req_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$currentUrl = $protocol . '://' . $host . $req_uri;

$hostArray = array("localhost", "host.integration", "10.105.0"); //Don't use minification on these urls


for ($i = 0; $i < count($hostArray); $i++) {
    if (strpos($currentUrl, $hostArray[$i])) {
        $useMin = false;
    }
}
```

However, using this method, you would be able to trigger the $useMin = false condition if you were to pass any of the strings in the host array as a parameter, for example:

```
http://domain.com?localhost
```

How do I write something that will prevent $useMin = false unless the URL starts with that condition (or is not contained anywhere after the ? in the url parameter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `$currentUrl` when checking `$hostArray`, just check to see if the `$host` itself is in the `$hostArray`.

If you want to check for an exact match:

```
if(in_array($host, $hostArray)) {
    $useMin = false;
}
```

Or maybe you want to do this, and check to see if an item in `$hostArray` exists anywhere within your `$host`:

```
foreach($hostArray AS $checkHost) {
    if(strstr($host, $checkHost)) {
        $useMin = false;
    }
}
```

And if you only want to find a match if `$host` *starts with* an item in `$hostArray`:

```
foreach($hostArray AS $checkHost) {
    if(strpos($host, $checkHost) === 0) {
        $useMin = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to make sure that the host doesn't contain $hostArray[$i] - but strpos doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I'll post here. Why do you check the host array with the url, why not check it directly with the host as in:

```
if (strpos($host, $hostArray[$i])) {
```

Comment: hey - this doesn't seem to work for some reason. Maybe I'm not understanding how this function works, but if I use your code above, and access the site at http://localhost - despite the fact that both $host and $hostArray[$i] echo as "localhost", that if conditional never triggers

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Use:

    if (strpos($host, $hostArray[$i]) !== false) {

The problem was when the match was at the begining.